# Why JavaScript IF only works once?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have JavaScript code which copies the value of input file and paste it in the text box in real time.

```
<script>
function copyit(){

var thephoto=document.getElementById('thephoto').value;
var fileonchange=document.getElementById('fileonchange').value;

if(!thephoto==fileonchange){
document.getElementById('fileonchange').value=thephoto;
}

}

window.setInterval("copyit()", 500);  
</script>

Choose File : <input type="file" id="thephoto"><br>
Here Is the file name : <input type="text" id="fileonchange">
```

Sadly this only works once and then stops pasting the value when changing the file again. (I mean you should reload the page to make it work again)

Does `IF` have a cache or something? You can try the code by yourself to see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. You need the `!=` operator to denote inequality:

```
if (thephoto != fileonchange) {
```

The `!thephoto` actually inverses its boolean representation (i.e. `true` becomes `false` and vice versa, also `null` becomes `true`). The `==` actually compares the equality of the both operands.

Comment: Honey, that's not related to gender :) Just have a good book/tutorial, motivation and mindset. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the IF line to:

```
if(thephoto!=fileonchange){
```

Answer (score 1):

[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602404/why-javascript-if-only-works-one-time/2602434#2602434) is completely right, but IMHO using a timer every 500ms to do this simple task seems pretty heavy.

Why don't you simply use the `onchange` event of the `<input type="file" />`?, e.g.:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var thephoto = document.getElementById('thephoto');
  var fileonchange = document.getElementById('fileonchange');

  thephoto.onchange = function () {
    // this function will be executed when the user changes the file
    fileonchange.value = this.value;
  };
};
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/acaho/2/).

Comment: CMS, Onchange doesn't work good on ie, you should click somewhere in the page to fire the function of pasting the value :(

Answer (score 1):

The input element, as the W3C says, accepts the `onchange` method. Why don't you do:

```
<input type="file" id="thephoto" onchange="copyit()">
```

Instead of using the dreaded setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

Use `!==` for strict inequality.

Or, if you want to use something similar to the syntax you've written, do this:

`if(!(thephoto==fileonchange)){`